# InfoPath 2013 unable to change table to repeating table

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath

I'm trying to create a table with a repeating row in InfoPath 2013 (editing a Sharepoint 2013 custom list in case that matters).  I'm unable to post a screenshot of the table to show you, but it is a 2-row, 2-column table with text in the first row, a Date/Time field in the 1st column of the 2nd row, and a text field in the 2nd column.

When trying to create this repeating table, I'm getting a prompt that says "InfoPath cannot automatically create a field or group in the section containing this control.  To set the binding, select a field or group in which to store the control's data:" (I would post a screenshot of this too, but reputation is too low)

Any ideas as to why this is happening?  I'm having trouble finding out exactly how repeating controls work in InfoPath and how to create them.

Comment: It might help if you show us your code.

Comment: How do I switch to a view where I can see the source code of the form?

Comment: firstly, you will need to create connection to you sharepoint list. once done, it will show on the side as data source. Now either you can drag drop or go to home, select repeating table and than select the repeating section from the list datasource. once done you can assign control for each fields.

Comment: When I created this form, I chose New SharePoint List and told it the location of my SharePoint server, so it should already be connected to SharePoint.  In my list of controls on the HOME tab, I don't have "repeating table".  If I start off with just a blank form completely, I see the Repeating Table control, but why does it not show this when I'm editing a form for a SharePoint custom list?

Comment: AFAIK Repeating tables aren't supported in list forms, because lists can't store repeating data in a single list item. To use repeating data, you should create a "Blank Form" template and publish it to a Form library.